# Change direction inside a p tag html

Tags: html, css

I want to change direction of a tag inside another tag but it does not work correctly.

in the following example i want to see `aslami @` exactly as i writed but in result it show `@` before `a` not after `i`.

```html
<p style="width: 100%; direction: rtl; text-align: right;">
  مهدی
  <em style="direction: ltr; text-align: left;">aslami @</em>
  خاوری
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `unicode-bidi:isolate;`<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-3/#propdef-unicode-bidi)</sup>

```html
<p style="width: 100%; direction: rtl; text-align: right;">
  مهدی
  <em style="direction: ltr;unicode-bidi:isolate; text-align: left;">aslami @</em>
  خاوری
</p>
```

But as also stated in the specification, you should better use `dir` than `direction`

> Because HTML UAs can turn off CSS styling, **we recommend HTML authors to use the HTML dir attribute and `<bdo>` element** to ensure correct bidirectional layout in the absence of a style sheet. **Authors *should* not use direction in HTML documents.**

---

You should also note that there is a slight difference between `dir` and `direction`.

For direction we have:

> ltr
>
> This value sets inline base direction (**bidi directionality**) to line-left-to-line-right. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-3/#direction)</sup>

For dir we have:

> The ltr keyword, which maps to the ltr state
>
> Indicates that the contents of the element are **explicitly directionally isolated** left-to-right text. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-dir-attribute)</sup>

So usiing `dir=ltr` is equivalent to `direction: ltr;unicode-bidi:isolate;` and not only `direction: ltr;`

<sup>See answer of [@Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56608510/8620333)</sup>

---

You can also consider `bdi` tag to do the same:

```html
<p style="width: 100%; direction: rtl; text-align: right;">
  مهدی
  <bdi><em style="direction: ltr; text-align: left;">aslami @</em></bdi>
  خاوری
</p>
```

> The bdi element represents a span of text **that is to be isolated from its surroundings** for the purposes of bidirectional text formatting <sup>[ref](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-bdo-element)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The css [`direction` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) is used mainly to set layout direction (see the 1st example in the link). Use the html [`dir` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) to set the text direction:

```html
<p dir="rtl" style="direction: rtl;">
  مهدی
  <em dir="ltr">aslami @</em>
  خاوری
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To shorten your code you can just use the attribute of dir alone on your HTML tag. Something like this. 
`

```html
<p dir="rtl" style="width: 100%; text-align: right;">
مهدی<em dir="ltr">aslami @</em>خاوری
</p>
```

`